# setInterval returns Timer Object and not intervalId

Tags: javascript, node.js, timeout, setinterval

I want to clear an interval by using its `intervalId` which I intend to store in a local file.

I was under the impression that assigning setInterval returns its `intervalId` but I seem to be getting `[object Timer]` instead.

---

```
var fs = require("fs");

var id = setInterval(function(){
  console.log("tick");
}, 1000);

console.log(id);

var stream = fs.createWriteStream("id");
stream.once('open', function(fd) {
  stream.write(id);
});
```

I am using node v4.9

Comment: Weird, it definitely returns an int for me (and it's documented to do so)..  Does node.js do something funky with setInterval maybe?

Comment: @MikeChristensen `setInterval` seems to be ticking correctly. What version of node are you using by the way?

Comment: It *should* [return the id](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.9/api/timers.html#setInterval), OTOH, [this post's console output](http://groups.google.com/group/nodejs/browse_thread/thread/341e7ee19a13e516?pli=1) shows something else after calling `setInterval`.

Comment: I'm not using node.js, I just tried with stand-alone Javascript.

Comment: Me thinks node.js mucks with the `setInterval` method and changes it, and their documentation is bad.  Can you look at the object in a debugger?  Maybe it has some numeric ID property you can log..

Comment: @MikeChristensen My `[object Timer]` has the following guts inside `{ repeat: 1, callback: [Function] }`

Comment: Why do you need to keep it in a file?

Comment: I guess this has been reported https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/747

Comment: Ah yea, definitely this is not the built in setInterval function then - maybe someone with some node.js expertise will chime in here with your answer :)

Comment: @DaveNewton I'm just exploring the possibilities of a setInterval to act like a cron job. These are just keys I'll probably end up sticking in a DB. That's another thread however. Thanks guys.

Comment: I think my ideas would be either 1) see if *another* version of node.js works as documented or 2) see if you can access the native window.setInterval function, or get a reference to it before you load node.js.

Comment: @MikeChristensen There's no `window` in a node.js app that I'm aware of, since there's no window. Node.js is a server-side JS implementation.

Comment: Oh sorry, my mistake - I was thinking it was a Javascript utility library.  I've heard of it but never really checked into what it was.

Comment: http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.5.10/api/timers.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a timer object, but clears the way you would expect it to:

$ node ./test.js

```
var id = setInterval(function(){
  console.log("FOO");
  console.log(id);
}, 500);

setTimeout(function(){
  clearInterval(id);
}, 5000);
```

Outputs the following for 5 seconds, and clears as expected:

```
FOO
{ repeat: 0, callback: [Function] }
FOO
{ repeat: 0, callback: [Function] }
FOO
{ repeat: 0, callback: [Function] }
```

More info: http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.5.10/api/timers.html